# wheelDeltaY (mousewheel event) cross-browser

Tags: javascript

wheelDeltaY of mousewheel event is currently supported by the Chrome and the latest version of Opera. How to make it cross-browser with pure javascript?

Comment: You'll have to check the browser type and use various mousewheel events to trigger